# Unable to Update on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, update, errors, jdbc, connectivity

This is a bit strange so bear with me please.

After installing a new **SQL Server 2008 R2** on a new server **(Windows 2012 Standard)** just like the production one, I tried to connect my web aplication **(Java/JDBC 4.0 Driver)** the same way I always do with the production server but this time my application was frozen for at least 15 minutes!

At the moment I thought: "Maybe it's something to do with privileges" but I was wrong because that user is the **db_owner** and has all the privileges on that database. 
So I decided to use the SQL Server Profiler to list all the queries arriving and executing when I login on the application. The usual "select" here and there but then I noticed **there was no "update" query trying to set the LastTimeLogin**, and at the same time my web application stopped working. I let the time pass so I can see what else was happening on the database. And guess what? Nothing happend for 15 minutes (aprox) :(

After that an exception occurred:

> Exception: Error saving LastLoginTime for account: demo
>   org.package.db.DBException: Update record 'demo'
>   [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: connection timeout]

Then I went back to the web browser and everything was working normally. The application could "insert", "update", "delete", "select".

I have to mention, locally the SQL Server works perfectly with Management Studio and remotely via TSQL (linux console client). The firewall is open for any SQL Server request.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a blocking issue - run `sp_who2` in Management Studio while your web server query is waiting and check the "blocked by" column.

Comment: I just did it and it shows a dot "." not a SPID.

Comment: I am not sure but please make sure 'Auto close' option is set false for the database

Comment: I checked that too and it is set to FALSE.